# Are instances of enums static by default?

Tags: java, enums

```
enum Animals{
    DOG("woof"),
    CAT("Meow"),
    FISH("Burble");

    String sound;

    Animals(String s) {
            sound = s;
    }
}
public class TestEnum{
    static Animals a;
    public static void main(String ab[]){
        System.out.println( a );
        System.out.println( a.DOG.sound + " " + a.FISH.sound);
    }
}
```

In the above example, why are we able to access instances of the enum (i.e. as a.DOG.sound) when `a` is null and enum is not declared as static?
Are the enum instances static by default?

Comment: The only difference between enum values and `static` is you can't place a `static { }` block before the enum values.

Comment: Why is this question tagged scjp?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Enums are implicitly `public static final`.

You can refer to `a.DOG` because you *may* access static members through instance references, even when null: static resolution uses the reference *type*, not the instance.

I *wouldn't*; it's misleading: convention favors type (not instance) static references.

See [JLS 6.5.6.2](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/names.html#6.5.6.2) regarding class variable via instances. See [JLS 15.11](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#41267) for why it still works with a `null`. Nutshell: it's the reference type, not the instance, through which statics are resolved.

---

## Updated links :/

**JSE 6**

- [JLS 6.5.6.2 regarding class variable access via expression name](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se6/html/names.html#33208)
- [JLS 15.11 regarding static field access via null references](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#d5e19902)

**JSE 7**

- [JLS 6.5.6.2 regarding class variable access via expression name](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.5.6.2-230-D)
- [JLS 15.11 regarding static field access via null references](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.11.1-210)

**JSE 8**

- [JLS 6.5.6.2 regarding class variable access via expression name](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.5.6.2-230-D)
- [JLS 15.11 regarding static field access via null references](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#d5e24541)

Comment: The Enum constants have public access. The class defaults to pacakage-private (default) access https://stackoverflow.com/a/23128025/731548

Comment: @cquezel Yes, the question asked about instances of enums.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, enums are effectively static.