# Static enum vs. Non-static enum

Tags: java, enums, static-members

What's the difference between static and non-static enum in Java? Both usages are same.

Is it correct that <del>*all static ones are loaded on memory on startup, and non-static ones are loaded on demand*?</del>
If yes, then which method is better? Keeping some data always in memory or using server resources to load them each time?

```java
public class Test {

    public enum Enum1 {
        A, B
    }

    public static enum Enum2 {
        C, D
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Enum1 a = Enum1.A;
        Enum1 b = Enum1.B;

        Enum2 c = Enum2.C;
        Enum2 d = Enum2.D;
    }
}
```

Comment: By properties you mean methods?

Answer (score 166, accepted):

All `enum`s are effectively `static`.  If you have a nested enum, it is much the same as a `static class`.

All classes are lazily loaded (enums or otherwise) however when they are loaded they are loaded all at once. i.e. you can't have a few constants loaded but not others (except in the middle of class initialization)

Java allows certain modifiers to be implicit to avoid having to declare them all the time.  This means that adding a modifier doesn't necessarily do anything other than provide a longer way of writing the same thing.

Default modifiers for

class field/method/nested class - package local, non-final, non-static

enum and nested enum - package local, final and static

interface field - `public static final`

interface method - `public abstract`

nested class in an interface - `public static`, non-final

Note: while `static` is optional for an `enum` it is always static.  However, `final` cannot be set for an enum even though it is always notionally `final` (Technically you can have subclasses with overridden implementations for constants)

EDIT: The only place you need to use `static` with `enum` is with `import static` of an enum's value. Thank you @man910

Comment: They may be implicit but if you forward reference them in static imports, you still need to declare them as static.

E.g., import static my.embedded.EnumType.SOME_VALUE;

Comment: FWIW this is not the case in Groovy despite Groovy's premise that valid Java is valid Groovy: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54139042/885922

Answer (score 23):

If you're talking about nested enums, they are implicitly `static` by default.

According to the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9):

> Nested enum types are implicitly static. It is permissible to
>   explicitly declare a nested enum type to be static.

Answer (score 15):

All Enums are implicitly static, its just you don't need to write the `static` keyword. Similarly to the way all interface methods are implicitly public.

Answer (score 4):

As `enums` are `inherently static`, there is no need and makes no difference when using `static-keyword` in `enums`.

If an enum is a member of a class, it is implicitly static.

Interfaces may contain member type declarations. A member type declaration in an interface is implicitly static and public.

[Oracle Community Forum and Discussion On This](https://community.oracle.com/message/8741436)