# Combining Java enums with dot syntax (enum.value1.value2)?

Tags: java, android, enums

I'm going through some existing (and working) code and came across a line like this:

```
if (someObject.getStatus() == SomeEnum.VALUE1.VALUE2) { ... }
```

Where SomeEnum is a simple enum that looks like this:

```
public enum SomeEnum {
    VALUE1,
    VALUE2,
    VALUE3,
    ...
}

private SomeEnum() {}
```

Now, what does that comparison above do? More precisely, what does the combination of two enum values in there do? I was astonished to not see any warnings or errors because of that line as I assumed this was simply wrong. However, it compiles and runs just fine. Can someone enlighten me on what this would do?

Comment: `Boolean.TRUE.FALSE` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (someObject.getStatus() == SomeEnum.VALUE1.VALUE2) { ... }
```

is equivalent to

```
if (someObject.getStatus() == SomeEnum.VALUE2) { ... }
```

`==` will compare the memory address on both sides for non-primitive types.

Answer (score 5):

You should get a warning about this if you're using an IDE like Eclipse, saying that `VALUE2` should be accessed in a static way. With `javac -Xlint:all` you will also get a warning. Other than this, `SomeEnum.VALUE1.VALUE2` is exactly the same as `SomeEnum.VALUE2`. The enum constants are represented as static fields.

Comment: Enums are implicitly [public static final](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8272957/are-instances-of-enums-static-by-default). Thats probably why he doesn't see the warning.

Comment: FYI, I'm using Android Studio and it does not give me a warning. Anyway, thanks for your answer (which happens to be pretty much identical to the one that came in a minute before yours).

Answer (score 2):

Do not use Enum in android http://developer.android.com/training/articles/memory.html#Overhead

(I couldnt do comments because of reputation problem so i wrote here. )

Comment: Now you can make comments

Comment: google says : Enums often require more than twice as much memory as static constants.  So we should avoid of using it. As an example from android developers, i can say that we are using serVisibility() method. It requires int variable. but we are giving Visible, invisible or gone. They are not enums. So , android developers are also using int instead of enum

Comment: Although that isn't an answer to the question at hand, I do appreciate that piece of information as I wasn't aware of that at all. Thanks!